# How to embed image as an attachment in AWS Cognito Forgot Password Custom Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

The usecase is to send send a customized email from AWS cognito when a user requests forgot password. Now, we need to add our company logo to the custom email. We earlier used the public URL for the logo in the `src` property of the `img` tag but due to certain security restrictions we cannot access the public s3 URLs now. I need to have a way where I can add the image to the email with `cid` property maybe or something similar. I appreciate your help.

Comment: base64 encode the image and just embed it directly into the html!?

Comment: Base64 encoding might increase the length of the email. And there is a limit to the number of characters. Correct? @luk2302

Comment: It will increase the length, yes. No idea if / what any length limits may be.

Comment: The limit is of 20K UTF-8 characters. Refer : https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-settings-user-invitation-message-customization.html